# Using pyo in python to make music

Tags: python, pyo

I have to make relaxing music using pyo package in python. I am not very experienced with audio processing . Any advice for that?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. In order to receive an answer, I suggest you to read [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: You want to *make* music and then even music that is "relaxing"? Time to study music theory and maybe years of work. Instead just google for and pick some library or open source music to use.

Comment: This problem is not with music theory. I have a basic understanding of that. The main issue is with audio processing terminology.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few examples on the GitHub and potentially other sources on the internet. I recommend checking it out and trying a few different experiments with the program to get an understanding to move forward. It might and probably will help https://github.com/belangeo/pyo